# In a <form onSubmit={}>, is the event data automatically passed?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm following along with a React tutorial on [Thinkster](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/react-redux-crud-api/example-2-implementing-create-functionality-for-comments) and noticed that the form has an onSubmit tag, which automatically passes on the event to be intercepted.

I did some quick research and couldn't seem to find any indication that this is normally what happens on an onSubmit. Am I missing something here? I just found it rather curious.

**From CommentInput.js**

```
        ...
        this.createComment = ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        const payload = agent.Comments.create(this.props.slug, {body: this.state.body});
        this.setState({body: ''});
        this.props.onSubmit(payload);
    };
}

render() {
            return (
                <form className="card comment-form" onSubmit={this.createComment}>
             ...
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Dont know if this will directly answer your question, but react events are synthetic and do not always behave the same as the standard dom events.

Comment: Hmm, this might be the answer. It's too bad there isn't something that might be a bit more concrete. Thanks!

Comment: @njho In general forms have an onSubmit handler.What is the confusion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `constructor()` method declare
`this.createComment= this.createComment.bind(this);` to remove auto submiting if it is the case of your question. But if you are asking that, are the data passed when you click submit button, then yes. They should be sent.